# react - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the example found here:

`https://github.com/mking/react-hn`

Unfortunately I get the following error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

In this code:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var NewsItem = require('./NewsItem');
var React = require('react');

$.ajax({
  url: '/json/items.json'
}).then(function (items) {
  // Log the data so we can inspect it in the developer console.
  console.log('items', items);
  // Use a fake rank for now.
  ReactDOM.render(
    <NewsItem item={items[0]} rank={1}/>,
    $('#content')[0]);
});
```

The actual line giving me the error is:

```
<NewsItem item={items[0]} rank={1}/>,
```

I've done similar examples where there's no issue not sure what makes this different.

Comment: Are you using a JSX transpiler?

Comment: thnx!  Yeah I'm using a JSX transpiler but I guess because this code wasn't hooked through my browserify it was causing the JSX to not be read properly.